# Trigger a script in php

Tags: php, file, include

First of all, I have a cron job for a php file. 
 Second of all, in the php file called by cron job i would like to call a file with a parameter. How could i do that without changing php.ini ?

Example:

```
include('file.php?id='.$id.');
```

Comment: What do you mean by `call a link with a parameter`?

Comment: "How could i do that without changing php.ini ?" --- how could you do that with changing php.ini? ;-)

Comment: Not sure about this but try exec()

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `file_get_contents()`:

```
file_get_contents('http://localhost/file.php?id='.$id.');
```

For more complex cases, you can have a look at PHP Curl.

Comment: Because file_get_contents doesnt parse the PHP in the file. It will output the source of file.php.

Comment: He wants to "call a link", he didn't say he needs the output or that he needs to parse the file.

Comment: i would like to trigger that "file" . Like pressing a button which has as action that file.

Comment: @Laurent: nope it won't. It would lead to a error that there is no such file

Comment: No it does not. It will output the file contents, unlike visiting the file in your browser. Also @zerkms has a very valid point, GET parameters obviously wont work on your filesystem.

Comment: Right, this can be fixed by adding localhost at the beginning. I've done that a few times for cron scripts and it works.

Answer (score 1):

including with get-parameters won't work, becasue the CLI-version of php doesn't support it. also include works on a file-system base, not on a url-base. include will/should search for the file file.php?id=1.  you should create a function an include the file by default, then call the function

including remote file with a url is a very very bad paractice. if you think you have to do this, your concept is simple broken. try to use an api/other kind of interface to interact with the remote-url.

Comment: This would work for simple cases but sometime it's not that obvious to refactor the code into a simple function. Think for example of a framework like Kohana - functions are within controllers that need to be correctly setup to work. In that case, calling the URL directly with Curl or file_get_contents is the simplest way.

Comment: I think it's a better way to load all the M(V)C-Stuff than calling a url. why involve a webserver  if you dont need one?
just in case everything wents wrong you can modify the $_SERVER-Global to set all the data

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in your other file, and call that in the original. For example:

file.php:

```
function someFunction($x)
{
 return $x*$x;
}
```

cron.php:

```
require 'file.php';
echo someFunction(10);
```

Also, any variable defined in the global scope will be available in the other file as well. For example, if you define $foo in cron.php you can use that value in file.php. Although this is not recommended, it is really hard to maintain a lot of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

According to include documentation, it is possible if the other php file is configured To parse .php and not .txt.
Try this code :

```
/* This example assumes that www.example.com is configured to parse .php
* files and not .txt files. Also, 'Works' here means that the variables
* $foo and $bar are available within the included file. */

// Won't work; file.txt wasn't handled by www.example.com as PHP
include 'http://www.example.com/file.txt?foo=1&bar=2';

// Won't work; looks for a file named 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2' on the
// local filesystem.
include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

// Works.
include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;
include 'file.txt';  // Works.
include 'file.php';  // Works.
```